# Laravel whereIn on a query with a relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, eloquent-relationship

Looked everywhere but couldn't find an answer

I have a similar query to this:

```
$users = User::with('contact')->get();
```

This would return something like:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Foo",
   "contact":[
      {
         "number":"123"
      },
      {
         "number":"456"
      },
      {
         "number":"789"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to create another query with another relation that would return entries where the number is in any of the above ones (123, 456, 789):

```
$admins = Admin::with('info')->whereIn('number', THE NUMBERS FROM THE FIRST QUERY)->get();
// Assumption is that numbers here is coming from the relationship, and info is a different table than contacts
```

Any help on how to achieve that is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your first query,

```
$users = User::with('contact')->get()->toArray();

$data = []
foreach($users as $a => $b) {
   foreach($b['contact'] as $c => $d) {
         $data[] = $d['number'];
    }
}
```

Second query :

```
$admins = Admin::with('info')->whereIn('number', $data)->get();
```